# Выделить с помощью regex слова, которые не между кавычек

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql, qregexp

Просьба помочь с регулярным выражением, задача такова, что нужно выделить слова, которые находятся НЕ между скобок, для примера:

> это не между "это между скобок слова" Это тоже не между "между" И это вне скобок

У меня получилось вот такое выражение, но оно цепляет некоторые слова в скобках:

```
(?<=\s|^)([а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]*?)(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: Так скобки или кавычки?

Comment: Можно и так - `"[^"]*"|([^"]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге еще посидев, сделал решение:

```
(?<="\s|^)([а-яА-Яa-zA-Z ]*)(?=\s"|$)
```

Comment: `Это "залёт, \" получается, "как мне" кажется`...

Comment: @Akina, так он же в тексте ищет, а не в код - откуда там быть экранированию?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не вижу ничего про "в тексте". И опять же то, что выглядит как текст с экранированием - тоже текст.

Comment: @Akina, но в вопросе нет ничего даже намекающего на экранирование.

Comment: @Qwertiy В вопросе вообще нет никаких ограничений на тестируемую строку. Ну а всё, что не описано явно, имеет право быть как угодно.